# PHP & MYSQL - ORDER BY id sometimes returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, random, web

I am trying to wrote a PHP script that will pull a random row from a MYSQL table. So far, the code successfully grabs a random row, but sometimes it will return nothing, and I don't understand why.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT fact 
                        FROM numfacts 
                        WHERE number = '".(string)$number."' 
                            AND id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM numfacts ) 
                        ORDER BY id 
                        LIMIT 1");
```

The value for `$number` is currently `12`, and there are two rows containing this in the database. Roughly 2/3 times the code returns a value, and the other 1/3 of times it returns 0 results.

If you need more code, I will provide it.

Comment: `ORDER BY id desc or ORDER BY id asc` what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the `WHERE` clause with `id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM numfacts )` restricts the query to looking in a subset of the table. If the two rows with `number = 12` are not in this subset, the query doesn't return anything. And since the subset is specified randomly, this will only happen some of the time.

To ensure that the subset includes at least one of the rows with `number = 12`, you can include that criteria in the subquery.

```
SELECT fact
FROM numfacts 
WHERE number = '".(string)$number."' 
    AND id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) 
               FROM numfacts
               WHERE number = '$number' ) 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1
```

Note that this query doesn't provide very fair selection of rows. Because it uses `ORDER BY id`, it's biased towards low-numbered rows. This method is reasonable when you're just trying to select a random row with no other filtering, but when you add the `number = 12` criteria it becomes unfair. For instance, if the IDs of the two rows are 50 and 75, you'll choose the lower one 2/3 of the time.

You can get an unbiased selection with:

```
SELECT fact
FROM numfacts
WHERE number = '$number'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I see, is there any other way I can get a more unbiased random?

Comment: Use `SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

If subquery `SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM numfacts` will return something less then `$number` the entire query will return nothing.

Comment: The query never compares that random number with `$number`.

Comment: My bad, there are `number` and `id` in condition. Your answer much more clear.